# Player Momentarily Stuck at Edges of Screen! Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am working on a Unity 2d game thats rounded about a player dodging random objects while flying...something like flappybird. the game work normal.

But the problem is when the player when touch the top screen edge and keep adding force the player get stuck a while on the edge. i think i need to disable adding force when the player touch the edge of the screen.
I hope u guys help me.
This the player code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jetpack: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameManager GameManager;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float jumpForce = 40f;
    private bool engineIsOn;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject fire;

    void Start()
    {
        engineIsOn = false;
        fire.SetActive(false);
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            engineIsOn = true;
            fire.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            engineIsOn = false;
            fire.SetActive(false);
        }


        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -4.5f, 4.5f),
        Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, -4.5f, 4.5f), transform.position.z);

        
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        switch (engineIsOn)
        {
            case true:
                rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce),ForceMode2D.Force);
                break;

            case false:
                rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 0f), ForceMode2D.Force);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

        GameManager.gameover();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever dealing with `Rigidbody` then don't set any values via the `Transform` component!

This might break the physics.

And then basically you already said it: Don't add more upwards force if you are on the edges.

As a simple trick you could set the Y velocity to 0 when hitting the edges like

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Very unusual to use a switch for a single bool
    if (engineIsOn)
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce),ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
    // This does absolutely nothing
    // Adding a force of 0,0 doesn't change the velocity at all ...
    //else
    //{
    //    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 0f), ForceMode2D.Force);
    //}

    // Check if currently hitting an edge
    // and if so set the velocity on that axis to 0
    // also clamp the position then
    var velocity = rb.velocity;
    var position = rb.position;
    if(Mathf.Abs(rb.position.x) >= 4.5f)
    {
        velocity.x = 0;
        position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, -4.5f, 4.5f);
    }
    if(Mathf.Abs(rb.position.y) >= 4.5f) 
    {
        velocity.y = 0;
        position.y = Mathf.Clamp(position.y, -4.5f, 4.5f);
    }
    rb.velocity = velocity;
    rb.position = position;
}
```

Comment: You said that transform component when dealing with rigitbody.
so what u suggest i should use instead to make player dont leave the screen edge ?